# Filtering a dataframe by specified column and specified value

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I do not know how to program in R at all, I only know python pandas. How to do the following in R:

- my code has two variables, username and asignment
- I want to filter my dataframe so that I only get the row that has `name == username`...
- and then I only want the the column whose name matches the variable `asignment`.

Pictured is how I did it in Python pandas just to make it clear what I want. How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the value you can use:

```
df$asgn1[df$name == username]
```

Or, using `dplyr` to get the column you can use `filter` and `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(name == username) %>%
  select(asgn1)
```

Comment: so the problem here is that i dont actually know that the value entered is asgn1. All i know is the variable assignment. How would I change the code to work if all i know is a variable?

Comment: @datasciencephl. If that is the ccase, it would be `df[[assignment]][df$name == username]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
df[df$name == username, assignment]
#[1] 80
```

Or you can also subset based on column position

```
df[df[, 1] == username, assignment]
```

---

In `dplyr` you could also use `pull` to get column name as vector

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(name == username) %>%
  pull(assignment)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Jenna", "Alex", "Nick"), asgn1 = c(80, 90, 92), 
                 asgn2 = c(82, 92, 94), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
username = "Jenna"
assignment = "asgn1"
```